# How can joins be nested in Laravel 4.2 Query Builder

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am trying to get a products list using Laravel 4.2 query builder.
The tables are related as follows

PRODUCTS
products.product_category_id

PRODUCT CATEGORIES
products.product_category_id = product_categories.id

PRODUCT CATEGORY TRANSLATIONS
product_categories.id = product_category_translations.product_category_id

What I am doing now is...

```
$products = DB::table('products')->join('product_categories', function($join){
    $join->on('products.product_category_id','=','product_categories.id');          
});
```

And I can get the contents of the product categories related table. But how can I nest another join and get the related data from the product categories translations table?

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to take a look at the laravel documentation to find a proper way to make relationship with models.
http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#relationships

You would then create models like

```
class Product extends Eloquent {
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('ProductCategory');
    }
}
class ProductCategory extends Eloquent {
    public function product()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Product');
    }
    public function translation()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Translation');
    }
...
```

Then to fetch the last table it would be as simple as something like :

```
$category = Category::find($categoryId);
$translation= $category ->translation;
```

Or if the id you have, is the productId, you can make it similar from the product table.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Maybe I did not explain myself well. My site is multilanguage so I can't have a one-to-one relationship for the categories translations. And I am asking how can I nest joins using Query Builder. I need to use Query Builder and not Eloquent because I am using yajra datatables package and it does not work properly with eloquent.